# Как вытащить числовое поле из таблицы и затем умножить его на числовое поле другой таблицы?

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Возник такой вопрос: как можно вытащить из одной таблицы поле числового значения и это поле умножить на поле другой таблицы, тоже числовое? Если можно, то в  одном запросе.

```
function edit_price() {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT dolar FROM kurs";
    $query = "UPDATE `goods` SET `price` = `price` * `dolar`";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['answer'] = "<div class='success'>Все цены товаров успешно обновлены!</div>";
        return true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['edit_kurs']['res'] = "<div class='error'>Ошибка!</div>";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Решил таким образом:

```
function edit_kurs() {
    global $connection;
    $dolar = (int) $_POST['dolar'];
    if (empty($dolar)) {
        // если поле пусто
        $_SESSION['edit_kurs']['res'] = "<div class='error'>Введите курс доллара в цифрах!</div>";
        return false;
    } else {
        if ($_POST) {
            $new_kurs = $_POST['dolar'];
        }
        $query = "UPDATE  goods, kurs  
        SET goods.price = (goods.price / kurs.dolar) * $new_kurs,
                kurs.dolar = $new_kurs ";
        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0) {
            $_SESSION['answer'] = "<div class='success'>Страница обновлена!</div>";
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажи, как ты хранишь курс доллара?

Comment: А дважды присваивать значение `$query` зачем? В смысле -- зачем присваивать первый раз, если в следующей строке оно затирается?

Comment: Вычислимые поля в базе не хранят, тем более такие простые (без агрегации и т.д.).

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, Где хранить? Если не этим способом. Если можете, покажите пожалуйста)

Comment: @Ale_x, а я WHERE date=NOW() не использую, я курс сам буду менять из админки:)

Comment: Их не надо хранить, их надо считать и выводить когда надо:

    select goodid, title, price*kurs.dollar as price
    from goods, (select dollar from kurs limit 1) kurs

где price содержит цену в базовой валюте (у вас в долларах).  

Рассчитанные цены (ну или пара цена в долларах, курс) хранятся только в заказе, т.к. в документах ничто не должно меняться, как только они выписаны. А прайс лист формируется хоть ежедневно по текущему курсу - **всегда рассчитывается**.  

ЗЫ На самом деле правильно хранить курсы по дата+валюта отдельными строками, запрос чуть другой получится.

Comment: @Alextrue,зачем заполнять курс руками, если их можно получать с rbc.ru  с помощью API

Comment: @Get, написал здесь, там нет возможности уже добавить комментарий, у меня в таблице два поля и одна строка, первое поле это id и второе поле это dolar. А переменной $old_kurs я немного не понял, что это.

Comment: $old_kurs - это переменная, подставляемая php скриптом, содержащая предыдущее значение курса. Перед тем, как ее подставлять надо ее заполнить чем-то. Лучше испрользовать все-таки другой вариант, с $new_kurs. Тогда надо просто получить из твоей формы $new_kurs с введенным тобой курсом доллара и выполнить 1 указанный запрос UPDATE к БД.

Comment: @Get, В БД вставляю запрос, который с $new_kurs, не получается, вот что выходит: #1054 - Unknown column '$new_kurs' in 'field list', то есть неизвестная колонка. А понял, что надо взять введенное число в поле это и будет $new_kurs, а как только его взять от туда? Писал сам и осознано.

Comment: @Alextrue, так же, как вы получаете значения из любой формы на сайте. Я думал функцию, приведенную в вопросе, вы писали самостоятельно. Почитайте про отправку форм и про программирование на php на сайтах в Yandex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если тебе надо пересчитать данные в таблице, то вот так (данные в таблице будут перезаписаны):

`UPDATE goods,kurs SET goods.price = goods.price*kurs.dolar`

это при условии, что в `kurs` всего одна строка и несколько полей:

```
euro | dolar | .... | krona
20   |   16  | .... |  10
```

**Обновление**

Я ж не знаю, откуда берется предыдущее значение курса. 
Насколько я понял, вы в одном окне задаете новые значения курса, сохраняете их, жмакаете кнопку и по этому нажатию пересчитываются цены.
В таком случае предыдущий курс станет неизвестен и его придется передавать отдельно. Для этого случая верно будет так:

```
$query = "UPDATE goods,kurs SET goods.price = (goods.price/$old_kurs)*kurs.dolar"
```

Если цены пересчитывать во время смены курса, то можно так:

```
$query = "UPDATE  goods, kurs  
  SET goods.price = ( goods.price / kurs.dolar )*$new_kurs ,
kurs.dolar =$new_kurs"
```

Comment: @Magos, Спасибо большое, а вот пользователь Get предложил в комментариях выше варианты, я думаю выбрать второй вариант: "Или второй вариант при UPDATE - берем цену, делим на предыдущее значение курса и умножаем на новое значение". А как это сделать в запросе или это указывается где-то в другом месте? Идея отличная)

Comment: @Magos, При таком запросе:

    $query = "UPDATE goods,kurs SET goods.price = (goods.price/$old_kurs)*kurs.dolar"

выходит ошибка:

>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')*kurs.dolar' at line 1.

Ну и при втором варианте запроса та же самая ошибка. (

Comment: @Magos, у меня две таблицы: в одной (это goods) хранятся товары с ценой (поле price), а в другой таблице (kurs) хранится поле dolar, где записан курс доллара в рублях. В админке я сначала просто меняю курс доллара первой кнопкой, а второй кнопкой уже перезаписываю новую цену в таблицу goods. И вывод на страницу магазина.

Comment: @Alextrue, вы считаете, что последовательность )kurs.dolar БД должна понять? 

Сделайте так ) * kurs.dolar

Comment: @Get, ну у @Magos так и есть в предложенном варианте, ну и у вас пробелы появились после ")" и после "*", попробовал тоже ошибка.

Comment: Что вы передаете в переменной $old_kurs? Понимаю, что старый курс, но возможно там пусто. В таблице kurs ведь только одна строка?

Answer (score 3):

Нормальное хранение курсов валют (любых данных, изменяющихся во времени). в 1С это называется периодический регистр сведений

```
Таблица kurs
period      | valuta| cost
10.12.2014     1        55.58
10.12.2014     2        65.58
09.12.2014     1        54.58
09.12.2014     2        64.58
```

Поле валюта - содержит id валюты из другой таблицы

Запрос - получить курс на указанную дату в примере на '2014-12-10'
В запросе выбираются все поля - что не нужно уберешь

```
SELECT period, valuta, cost
FROM kurs
RIGTH JOIN
(
    SELECT max(period) as maxperiod, valuta as tvaluta
    FROM ostatki
    WHERE period<='2014-12-10'
    and valuta=' id нужной валюты'
    GROUP BY valuta //если идет запрос конкретной валюты - это можно убрать, если запрос курсов нескольких валют это оставить
) as tp
on period=maxperiod and valuta=tvaluta
```

Answer (score 2):

Вставить вложенный SELECT можно. Типа SET price=price*(SELECT kurs FROM kurses WHERE date=NOW() ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1). Должно заработать.

Comment: @Get, Сделал так:  $query = "UPDATE goods SET price = price*(SELECT dolar FROM kurs)"; Не работает(

Comment: Конечно, у тебя вложенный SELECT вытягивает все значения dolar из таблицы kurs и БД не понимает, на какое именно из них надо умножать. Тестируй запросы в phpmyadmin - там сразу ошибки видно будет.

Comment: @Get, а у меня только одно значение, и все.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает запрос?

Comment: @Get, Срабатывает вот это условие, и все:

    $_SESSION['edit_kurs']['res'] = "<div class='error'>Ошибка!</div>";

Comment: Я же говорил, тестируйте SQL запросы в phpmyadmin, а потом скажите, какая ошибка там выводится. Пока мы видим, что в переменную сесии edit_kurs[res] записывается слово Ошибка. Добавьте в запросе в конце LIMIT 1, чтобы БД поняла, что вы отдаете отчет своим действиям, когда просите умножить число на все значения столбца.

Comment: @Get, Странно, как протестировал в БД, так сразу заработало, а все так же не изменилось в запросе. А я тут  подумал, это же я обновляю цену товара по курсу доллара, а вот если цена доллара упадет, то цена товара будет постоянно умножаться на уже полученное число, как быть ч тем, чтобы при понижении доллара, цену убавлять?))

Comment: Хранице цену в вашей валюте, и цену, рассчитанную с учетом курса доллара для скорости работы БД. При запросе UPDATE цену на товар берите в вашей валюте, умножайте ее на курс доллара, а затем - записывайте в колонку с ценой, учитывающей курс. При SELECT - сразу из поля с рассчитанным значением от курса доллара. 

Или второй вариант - берем цену, делим на предыдущее значение курса и умножаем на новое значение.

Comment:  WHERE date=NOW()  -мда...
Представьте что будет с вашим запросом если курс на текущую дату в таблице не существует - это как правило суббота и воскресение - курсы не меняются.